# Flask with Socket.IO on Gunicorn, Nginx, Docker, and Google Cloud VM: Persistent 400 Bad Request and Connection Timed Out Errors"

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, flask-socketio

**Environment Setup:**

- I'm developing a Chrome extension that interacts with a Flask application using Socket.IO.
- The Flask application is served using Gunicorn.
- Nginx is employed as a reverse proxy.
- The application is containerized using Docker.
- This Docker container is deployed on a Google Cloud VM.
- My domain is connected to the GCP VM, serving the extension's backend.

**Errors Observed:**

- On the client-side (within the Chrome extension), I've encountered errors in the JavaScript console related to failed socket connections. These include 400 (BAD REQUEST) and 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) HTTP statuses.

Docker File:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary tools for compilation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc libpcre3-dev python3-dev libssl-dev

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY ./backend /backend

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /backend/requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONPATH /backend:$PYTHONPATH

# Run gunicorn when the container launches with configurations for Flask-SocketIO
CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker", "-w", "1", "app:app", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Python app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

from utils import get_html_content, get_chunks, feed_LLM, get_embeddings, retrieve_most_relevant_chunks
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/summarize": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode="gevent", logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
    print('Client connected')


@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnection():
    print('Client disconnected')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Welcome to my app!"


document_chunks = []


@app.route('/summarize', methods=['POST'])
def summarize():
    extracted_text = []
    progress = 0  # Initialize the progress to zero
    try:
        selected_links_data = request.json.get('selectedLinks', [])
        print("Received links:", selected_links_data)
        summaries = []

        total_links = len(selected_links_data)
        progress_per_link = 100.0 / total_links
        progress_increment = progress_per_link / 4  # since there are 4 progress updates for each link

        for link_data in selected_links_data:
            link = link_data.get('url')
            title = link_data.get('title')

            html_content = get_html_content(link)
            if html_content:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
                paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
                text = ' '.join([p.get_text() for p in paragraphs])
                text = text.replace("\xa0", " ")

                extracted_text.append(text)

               chunks = get_chunks([text])

                progress += progress_increment
                socketio.emit('progress_update', {'step': progress, 'message': 'Document embeddings in progress...'})
                document_embeddings = [get_embeddings(chunk) for chunk in chunks]

                progress += progress_increment
                socketio.emit('progress_update', {'step': progress, 'message': 'Getting user query embedding...'})
                user_query_embedding = get_embeddings("Analyze the main points of this contract and give a summary")

                progress += progress_increment
                socketio.emit('progress_update', {'step': progress, 'message': 'Retrieving relevant chunks...'})
                relevant_chunks = retrieve_most_relevant_chunks(user_query_embedding, document_embeddings, chunks)

                response = feed_LLM(relevant_chunks)
                progress += progress_increment
                socketio.emit('progress_update', {'step': progress, 'message': 'Feeding to LLM for summary...'})

                summaries.append({
                    "title": title,  # use the title from the payload
                    "content": response
                })

        return jsonify({"summaries": summaries}), 200

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return jsonify({"error": "An error occurred during summarization."}), 500


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), socketio.wsgi_app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler).serve_forever()
```

Nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sleeplessai.com www.sleeplessai.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sleeplessai.com www.sleeplessai.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sleeplessai.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/sleeplessai.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Configurations and Attempts:

- I've set up Flask-SocketIO with CORS allowed from all origins and with async_mode set to "gevent".
- For debugging i've tried various configurations, including adjusting proxy headers and timeouts in the Nginx configuration.
- Chrome extension's manifest file has content_security_policy set to allow connections to my domain https://sleeplessai.com.

I have been monitoring the logs for both the Docker container and the access and error log files for nginx. All of these files show no errors thrown but still no connection.

Comment: The server logs are necessary to troubleshoot this. Both from Nginx and Gunicorn.